# Gridview Calendar Extender get date

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a GridView which allows users to enter data using a EmptyDataTemplate. There is a text box having a calendarextender. I want to get the date entered (format MM/dd/yyyy) and pass it to the database.

Please let me know how to do it.

My code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GV_Rotl_Asgt" runat="server" EnableModelValidation="True" 
               BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None"
                            BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" Font-Names="Arial" 
                  Font-Size="8pt" GridLines="Vertical"                                
                            AllowSorting="True" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                           Width="1196px"                                                              
                           ShowFooter="True" OnRowCommand="GV_RowCommand" DataKeyNames="Emplid">

             <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
             <PagerSettings PageButtonCount="1000" />
             <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
             <Columns> 
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#00349C"> 
                       <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:LinkButton ID="btnEdit" Text="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" CssClass="infotitle" /> <br /> 
                         <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" Text="Delete" runat="server" CommandName="Delete"  CssClass="infotitle"/> 
                       </ItemTemplate>
                       <EditItemTemplate> 
                         <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdate" Text="Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update"  CssClass="infotitle" />
                         <asp:LinkButton ID="btnCancel" Text="Cancel" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel"  CssClass="infotitle"/>
                       </EditItemTemplate>
                       <FooterTemplate>
                         <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Insert" Text="Insert" CommandName="InsertNew" CssClass="infotitle" />
                         <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Cancel" Text="Cancel" CommandName="CancelNew" CssClass="infotitle" />
                       </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField> 
                 </Columns>
                 <EmptyDataTemplate>
                 <table id="NoDatatbl" width="100%" style="margin-right: 0px">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="ColumnHead" width="150px">
                             To Date</td>
                      <td class="ColumnHead" width="150px">
                             From Date</td>
                      <td class="ColumnHead" width="150px">
                             Rotational Assignment</td>
                      <td class="ColumnHead" width="150px">
                             Location</td>
                      <td class="ColumnHead" width="150px">

                       </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table id="NoDatatbl1" width="100%" style="margin-right: 0px">
                    <tr>
                      <td class="ColumnHead" width="150px">
                           <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="NodataToDt" format="MM/dd/yyyy"/> 
                          <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="NodataToDt" format="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
                         </td>
                      <td class="ColumnHead" width="150px">
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="NodatafrmDt" format="MM/dd/yyyy"/>
                            <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="NodatafrmDt" format="MM/dd/yyyy"/>

                            <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="NodatafrmDt" ControlToCompare="NodataToDt" Operator="GreaterThanEqual"
                              Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="From Date should be greater than To Date" 
                             Type="Date"></asp:CompareValidator>
                          <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="CompareValidator1_ValidatorCalloutExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="CompareValidator1">
                            </asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>


                             </td>
                      <td class="ColumnHead" width="150px">
                              <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="NodataRotl" /></td>
                      <td class="ColumnHead" width="150px">
                              <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="NodataLoc" /></td>
                      <td class="ColumnHead" width="150px">
                       <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="LinkButton1" Text="Insert" CommandName="NoDataInsert" CssClass="infotitle" />
                       </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                 </EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Basically, I want to fetch the values from the NodataToDt & NodatafrmDt textboxes in codebehind and pass the values to my stored procedure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code behind:

```
// Find the 2 text boxes within your GridView control
TextBox toDateTextBox = (TextBox)GV_Rotl_Asgt.FindControl("NodataToDt");
TextBox fromDateTextBox = (TextBox)GV_Rotl_Asgt.FindControl("NodatafrmDt");

// Grab the values out of those text boxes
string toDate = toDateTextBox.Text;
string fromDate = fromDateTextBox.Text;
```

From there, you can do whatever you need with those two string values.